# How can I make Ghidra have access to external libraries?

Tags: x86, ghidra

I am trying to decompile a executable file, I have the source code of the external libraries that it is using, I wonder if there is a way that I can make Ghidra recognize these libraries, just like it does with windows calls, e.g: `fopen`,`printf`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, this is what should be done in order for Ghidra to have access to external libraries.

For the following C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
    return 1;
}
```

Compile the code with your favorite compiler, I choose clang. With the compiler front-end, `clang code.c -o code` that will produce an executable.

In Ghidra create a new project and import the executable file to Ghidra either by dragging the file to the Project or in the menu choose "file" and press "Import File" (Press I in the keyboard) and choose the executable file.

After importing the executable file Ghidra will show you a Dialog:

[image: Ghidra Import Dialog]

In the Dialog click on Options and a new window will appear:

[image]

Tick "Load External Libraries" and press "OK" twice. Ghidra will locate and import the necessary external libraries to your project.